# I'm trying to add a specific member inside ArrayList of ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to add a play card to a list of cards for the players (player 0 and player 1). I tried to be generic and to implement the code that will be easy to change for a game of n players. But, I'm confused with the syntax, adding a new card for a specific player isn't work... Please help:

```
public class GameThread extends Thread{
private Socket socket = null;
private Socket[] connections = new Socket[2];
private List<List<Card>> player = new ArrayList<List<Card>>();

CardPack cardPack = new CardPack(); //creating a new card pack

public GameThread(int sessionID, Socket s) {
    socket = s;
//      Initial card for two players
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        player.add(0, this.cardPack.getRandomCard());
        player.add(1, this.cardPack.getRandomCard());

    }
}
```

PS. This is a specific problem with a specific answer. Thanks  Sotirios Delimanolis, Tunaki for your help of signing my question as a duplicate to question of somebody who transfers tables from SQL to ArrayLists, but why to change the reputation?

Real T H A N K S for InfernalRapture

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: It's a list<list<object>> you can't just add objects to a list<list> like that. You need to do `player[index].add(new Card())` format. Or define `List<Card> person1`, `List<Card> person2` and add them from there

Answer (score 0):

```
player.get(0).add(cardPack.getRandomCard());
player.get(1).add(cardPack.getRandomCard());
```

I'd recommend naming the two players for future reference, since you'll probably need to use them repeatedly.

```
public class GameThread extends Thread{
private Socket socket = null;
private Socket[] connections = new Socket[2];
private List<List<Card>> players = new ArrayList<List<Card>>();

CardPack cardPack = new CardPack(); //creating a new card pack

public GameThread(int sessionID, Socket s) {
    socket = s;
//      Initial card for two players
    List<Card> playerOne = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Card> playerTwo = new ArrayList<>();
    players.add(playerOne);
    players.add(playerTwo);
    playerOne.add(this.cardPack.getRandomCard());
    playerTwo.add(this.cardPack.getRandomCard());
    }
}
```